# Should child process always call exit() rather than return?

Tags: c, fork, xv6

When I was writing solutions for the lab of MIT6.s081, I encountered the problem that the lab requires to write a bash command `find` in xv6.
My code are following:

```c
#include "kernel/types.h"
#include "kernel/stat.h"
#include "user/user.h"
#include "kernel/fs.h"

char* getFmtFile(char *path){
    static char buf[DIRSIZ + 1];
    char *p;

    for(p = path + strlen(path); p >= path && *p != '/'; p--){
        ;
    }
    p++;

    if(strlen(p) >= DIRSIZ)
      return p;
    memmove(buf, p, strlen(p));
    memset(buf + strlen(p), 0 , DIRSIZ - strlen(p));
    return buf;
}

void find(char* dir, char* file){
    char buf[512], *p;
    int fd;
    struct dirent de;
    struct stat st;

    if(( fd = open(dir, 0)) < 0){
        fprintf(2, "find : cannot open %s\n", dir);
        return;
    }

    if(fstat(fd, &st) < 0){
        fprintf(2, "find : cannot stat %s\n", dir);
        close(fd);
        return;
    }


    //printf("Successfully open director,dir :  %s, file : %s\n", dir, file);
    switch(st.type){
        case T_FILE:
            //printf("Current file is %s\n", getFmtFile(dir));
            if(strcmp(getFmtFile(dir), file) == 0){
                fprintf(1, "%s\n", dir);
            }
            break;

        case T_DIR:
            if(strlen(dir) + 1 + DIRSIZ + 1 > sizeof buf){
                printf("find : path too long\n");
                break;
            }
            strcpy(buf, dir);
            p = buf + strlen(buf);
            *p++ = '/';
            while(read(fd, &de, sizeof(de)) == sizeof(de)){
                //char* cur = getFmtFile(de.name);
                char *cur = de.name;
                //printf("Current file : %s\n",cur);
                if(de.inum == 0 || strcmp(cur, ".") == 0 || strcmp(cur, "..") == 0)
                  continue;
                memmove(p, de.name, DIRSIZ);
                p[DIRSIZ] = 0;
                if(stat(buf, &st) < 0){
                    printf("find: cannot state %s\n", buf);
                    continue;
                }
                find(buf, file);
                //printf("%s %d %d %d\n", getFmtFile(buf), st.type, st.ino, st.size);
                //printf("Get out of find\n");
            }
            break;
    }
    close(fd);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 3){
        fprintf(2, "Usage: find [directory] [file name]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
//  printf("find %s in %s\n", argv[2], argv[1]);
    find(argv[1], argv[2]);
    exit(0);
    //return 0;
}
```

In my concept, `return 0` equals `exit(0)` in `main function`. The bash forks a child process to do `find`, it will exit when I call return 0. But there seems something goes wrong when I use return rather than exit.

[Return result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVMsk.png)

which seems the program doesn't finish after return?

Comment: When you check the loop end of `for(p= ...` you might be comparing `p` with `path` when `p` is `path - 1`. This isn't a valid pointer. A pointer which points to one element *past* the object is a valid pointer (and can't be referenced), but a value of one element *before* the object isn't even a valid pointer.

Answer (score 2):

A `return 0` from `main` should be the same as `exit(0)`. Please see C18 which has

> **5.1.2.2.3 Program termination**
>
> 1 If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`, a `return` from the initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument; reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0. If the return type is not compatible with `int`, the termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.